# Configuring QoS For Huawei Modems

Tags: modem, qos

I've researched this subject but found absolutely 0 result for my router. I want to configure my router's QoS settings and give my all bandwidth to uTorrent application, so (I hope) I can download my torrents with better speed.

My router is Huawei HG630a (no support for DD-WRT) .

These are screenshots of QoS page on modem configuration panel (192.168.1.1)
[image]
[image]

As you can see there is no option for select uTorrent application but most of the QoS guides on internet talking about this option. Also it's asking for Source MAC, Target MAC, Source IP etc... I have no idea how to fill this fields.

So, is it possible to configure QoS for boost uTorrent's speed on my router? If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: QoS doesn't really affect downloads since you have no control over how fast something is sent to you. QoS lets you define a fairness to be applied to traffic within your network, and how things are buffered, queued, or policed when leaving your network. QoS policies only work inside your network because nobody outside your network trusts your concept of fairness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QoS will only change the priorities. It will only make a difference if/when all the available bandwidth is used.

If you're downloading torrents at 100 kB/s on a line that can do 1 MB/s forget it, it will change nothing.

Comment: Actually I want to give all of the available bandwidth to uTorrent. While downloading a torrent I can watch a video really fast from Youtube, browse internet. So, it's mean , uTorrent isn't using all of the bandwidth. I want to give full bandwidth to uTorrent and limit other activities on the internet

Comment: OK. You don't have to fill everything. Just set destination port to the torrent port (forgot what it is, but you redirected the port on the router right) and assign that to the queue 1 and the rest (leave everything empty?) to queue 2.

Answer (score 0):

just use the bandwidth allocation options on Utorrent.. right click the file which you are downloading. there is a option called "bandwidth allocation" at the bottom.. and click the set download speed. you can play with the setting as you like.